# inaccurate calculation caused by inaccurate data type use

Tags: c, math

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
  int num,onum,numl=0,tem,nnum=0;    

  printf("Enter num: ");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  onum =num;

  while (num!=0){
    num = num/10;
    ++numl;
  }
  num = onum;

  while (num!=0){
    tem = num%10;

    nnum += pow(tem,numl);
    printf("%d",nnum);
    num /= 10    ;
  }

  if (nnum == onum){
    printf("is");
  }
  else{
    printf("not");
  }
}
```

works fine with other Narcissistic numbers .

but when input 153 , 5**3 is mistakenly counted to 124, why?
[image]

---

This question is duplicate of [many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32356961/8491106). And the answer below is the most easy-to-understand anwer.

In one sentence, the inaccurate calculation is caused by {inaccurate {data type usage} or {compiler} or {FPU} }.

I **avoided** the error by updating my compiler to gcc 7.2 . But **solving** the problem needs a pow function for integer.

Comment: try to add more details, using spam to fill in words is a bad practice

Comment: [Why pow(10,5) = 9,999](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9704195/995714), [Will (int)pow(n,m) be wrong for some positive integers n,m?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32353301/995714), [return value of pow() gets rounded down if assigned to an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7937286/995714)

Comment: the general solution is to round the results to the nearest integer

Comment: I edit it to correct my wrong word-use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pow` (in `pow(tem,numl)`) is a floating point function. It means that it returns a `double`, bound to floating point inaccuracy and rounding (if `pow` returns `124.999999` it has no impact for floating point computation, but it does when assigned to an integer because of truncation)

So relying on the return value of `pow` may work, or may not (depends on the values, the FPU, the compiler math libraries). And the fact that "sometimes it issue a slightly off value" is a giveaway for that floating point inaccuracy issue.

Since you're working exclusively with integers, I would use integer exponentiation instead, either with a simple loop or with more complex algorithms ([The most efficient way to implement an integer based power function pow(int, int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int))

Comment: I am interested, why then this code work in my case - Ubuntu 16.04, `gcc version 5.4.0`?

Comment: this code works for me too (gcc 6.1). But it depends on the FPU and on the math library. It's better _not_ to depend on it and use strictly integer arithmetic. thanks for your comment. I have updated the answer.