# Why does pow() subtract 1 from my result?

Tags: c, math, codeblocks

I'm new with C programming, and I've written this code as I've been asked to do something using mainly printf() and scanf(). I know there could be better ways to handle this, which I'll need to learn soon, but anyways, for now this is what I have:

```
int add1, add2, exponent, exponent_result, multiplier, parenthese, product, sub, total;

printf("Let's try a slightly more complex calculation, in which we'll use an exponent.\n\n");
printf("Type 5 whole numbers or integers.\n\n");
scanf("%i %i %i %i %i", &add1, &add2, &exponent, &multiplier, &sub);
printf("Out of the numbers you typed, we're going to make this operation: (%i + %i^%i) * %i - %i\n\n", add1, add2, exponent, multiplier, sub);

exponent_result = pow(add2, exponent);
parenthese = add1 + exponent_result;
product = parenthese * multiplier;
total = (add1 + exponent_result) * multiplier - sub;

printf("Per PEMDAS, the correct order of operation is Parentheses, then Exponents, then Multiplications and Divisions, and finally Additions and Subtractions.\n\n");
printf("Therefore: (%i + %i^%i) * %i - %i\n\n", add1, add2, exponent, multiplier, sub);
printf("...is equal to: (%i + %i) * %i - %i\n\n", add1, exponent_result, multiplier, sub);
printf("...is equal to: %i * %i - %i\n\n", parenthese, multiplier, sub);
printf("...is equal to: %i - %i\n\n", product, sub);
printf("...is equal to: %i", total);
```

If you run this code, you'll realize that the output for exponent_result, which is calculated using the `pow() function`, always has 1 subtracted from it. For instance, if exponent_result is supposed to be the result of `5^3`, the result for that will be `124` instead of `125`.

What am I doing wrong?

Fyi, I have this at the beginning of my file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
```

Comment: Had you checked your problem. As while I tried to run your program it working fine. Without any issue. If you still have problem share the online ide runnable code so that we can check the issue. I got the proper output. Do you want to say that the input what you have placed are having certain issue?

Comment: do not try to use float atirthmetics for integer calculations. Integers are always precise, floats are almost always not. I

Comment: Avoid truncation, round instead `exponent_result = lround(pow(add2, exponent));`

Answer (score 7):

`pow` is evaluated in *floating point arithmetic*, and is probably implemented as `pow(x, y) = exp(y * log(x))`.

This can cause the result to "go off": you probably get a value just shy of 125, which is truncated to 124 when the `double` return type from `pow` is converted back to an `int`.

The simplest remedy is to build your own `pow` function for integral arguments. See [The most efficient way to implement an integer based power function pow(int, int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int)

Comment: seems that using `5` as radix triggers that often: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960102/inaccurate-calculation-caused-by-inaccurate-data-type-usage/45960231#45960231 (asked 2 days ago :))