# C++ Array of binary numbers to int value

Tags: c++, arrays, string, binary, decimal

everyone ! Now I am stuck here with a problem...

Problem:

> Given a binary number represented as an array, write a function that
> takes the array and its size as a parameter, and returns the integer
> value. You may assume that there are at least 1 and no more than 30
> numbers in the array and that all the values are either 0 or 1. The
> array is ordered with most significant binary digit at the start
> (index 0) and the least significant digit at the end.
>
> ```
> Signature: int binary_to_number(int binary_digits[], int number_of_digits)
> ```

The function I have wrote is at the bottom.
It works fine to return the int value for ***number_of_digits <= 10***.

As you can see, that the question says "You may assume that there are at least 1 and no more than 30 numbers in the array"

My question is, how can I fix my function to return proper int value even if there is more than 10 numbers (perhaps 30 numbers)?

OR, Should I be approaching the problem different way? and if so, what should I do?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int binary_to_number(int binary_digits[], int number_of_digits){
    std::string bin_str;

    for (int i=0; i<number_of_digits; i++) {
         if (binary_digits[i] == 0) {
             bin_str = "0" + bin_str;
         } else if (binary_digits[i] == 1) {
             bin_str = "1" + bin_str;
           } 
    }
    int bin_int = std::stoi (bin_str);
return bin_int;
}
```

Comment: "It works fine to return the int value for number_of_digits <= 10" How do you know, that it works fine for less, and for more not? Which test cases did you use?

Comment: Your function is odd. It takes an array like `[1001]`, then converts it to a string `"1001"`, and converts that to an int, which is `1001`. The answer should actually be `9` it seems.

Comment: Maybe `return static_cast<int>(std::bitset<30>(bin_str).to_ulong());`?  Of course this assumes `bin_str` is created correctly.

Comment: you misunderstood the assignment two ways. First it says that the most significant bit comes first, but you put it last, then you should convert to decimal. Your function returns `1` for input `{1,0}` but it should be `2`

Comment: the thing is that once you do what the assignments asks for, the problem with number of digits will probably be gone. Right now you are limited by digits of an `int` but you don't really need to hit that limit

Comment: Oh no, I think I completely misunderstood the problem itself... thank you everybody for the correction ! I think I may know what to do now !

Comment: The point of this exercise is that you learn how a binary number is built up from powers of two and a decimal number of powers of ten. The point is not the conversion itself. (In most learning exercises, the method and how to reach it is the point, not the result.)

Answer (score 0):

first of all u are using 0 and 1's in your string so assume your array is of 30 length then string will also be of 30 length but
max size of long long even is 18 digits you will get overflows

```
int bin_int = std::stoi (bin_str);
```

above is completely wrong...

You must convert the binary to integer the old way in powers of 2 then if u want to convert it to  `int` no problem but i would suggest you to do like this instead else your approach will be messy

```
num += pow(2,i); // watch out for overflows if u experience such; then 
                 // better use bit manipulation for 2's power eg.(1<<i)
```

here no problem just the old way.....But it's starting from LSB . From MSB you have to start from last of array  as per your question

Comment: Do not use `pow`.  It is a floating point function that can yield results that are not exact.

Comment: then use bit manipulation but powers of two cut to int no problem

Comment: int x = pow(2,1) will be 2 only not 2.000 or 0

Comment: other way can be bitset but i assume u need help with function not bitset

Comment: You could go into a while loop and use left shifting, bitwise or, division and modulus. The classic way.

Comment: Oh it's in an array even better just shifting and bitwise or

Comment: of course an `int` cannot be `2.000` but `pow(2,1)` is actually `pow(2.0,1)` and it does return a floating point value which when truncated to an `int` can yield wrong/unexpected results

Comment: for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122496/wrong-output-by-power-function-c there are many more

Comment: well ok i read the above and thanks for edit....although i never faced problem until now does'nt mean it does'nt mean it exists any way i would suggest bit manipulation again if the guy knows or bitset.............

Answer (score 0):

You may use this algorithm to do so:

```
int conversion(int array[], int len) {
    int output = 0;
    int power = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        output += array[(len - 1) - i] * power;
        // output goes 1*2^0 + 0*2^1 + 0*2^2 + ...
        power *= 2;
    }

    return output;
}
```

A sample statement could be considered as:

```
int arr[16] = {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1};
std::cout << conversion(arr, 16);
```

Then it should out:

```
39321
```

A beautiful representation for my code could be found [here](http://tpcg.io/2cNjjooo).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't understand.  Why not use the left bit shift operator, `<<`?;

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I've no idea for working with bit operators yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing more operations than necessary.

```
int result = 0;
int index = number_of_digits - 1;
for (int i = 0U; i < number_of_digits; ++i)
{
  result = (result << 1) | binary_digits[index];
  --index;
}
```

The result is initialized to zero.
For each bit in the array:
  Left shift the result by one bit to make room for the new bit.
  Arithmetic OR the new bit.

Try out the algorithm by hand.